# The request has exceeded the allowable time limit & Java Heap Space Null errors

Tags: java, mysql, coldfusion, jvm

I know this topic seems to be discussed many times, but I have tried all the methods mentioned to no avail.

I am keeping getting the errors:

> The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: CFQUERY 
>   
> The error occurred on line 152.

and also

> Java heap space null 
> The error occurred on line -1.

on the same html page.

I believe the Java heap space error is causing the timeout or vice versa.

The program where the time out occur is

```
        <CFQUERY DATASOURCE="#datasource#" USERNAME="#username#" PASSWORD="#password#" NAME="myQuery" CACHEDWITHIN="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,5,0)#">
    SELECT tableA.productid, tableA.userid, tableA.salesid, tableA.productname, tableA.price, tableA.units, tableA.currency, tableA.terms, tableA.description, tableA.pic, tableA.minorder, tableA.salesid, tableB.id, tableB.company, tableB.city, tableB.state, tableB.country, tableB.contact, tableB.skype
    FROM tableA LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.userid = tableB.userid
        WHERE tableA.category = <cfqueryparam value = "#cat#" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer" maxLength = "2">
        ORDER by tableA.ranks DESC
        </CFQUERY>
```

which I don't know how it can be further "optimized"?  It's only retrieving about 28,000 resulting records, *not* 2 millions.  I am using MySQL database.

I have increased my MaxPermSize from 256MB to 512MB but it seems the problem is still occurring, especially when search engines coming to site to index.  I am running on CF9 on a server with 6GB RAM.  Here are some of my settings in CF:

- Minimum and Maximum JVM Heap Size are both set at 512MB.
- Timeout Requests after ( seconds) set at 60
- JVM version 1.7.0_67
- JVM Arguments:

  > -server -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xbatch -Dcoldfusion.rootDir={application.home}/../ -Dcoldfusion.libPath={application.home}/../lib

Any suggestion is welcomed.  Thanks in advance.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

1. There are 26 categories of products
2. Each category has 20-50K records and is increasing daily
3. People may or may not accessing all 26 different categories at different time during the day
4. Not all categories are updated daily but some categories are

Comment: Once you have those 28,000 records, what are you doing with them?

Comment: To test whether the error is related to the number of rows fetched from the database query, you could add a LIMIT clause, at the end of the MySQL SQL statement, following the ORDER BY clause... **`ORDER BY tableA.ranks DESC LIMIT 1`**. This doesn't "fix" the problem, it only helps determine whether the error is related to the number of rows returned by the query.  (I'm not seeing -Xms and -Xmx arguments in the JVM settings, you indicate they are both set to 512m.)

Comment: As far as "optimizing" the MySQL query, I'd take the actual SQL text to another client, and run EXPLAIN EXTENDED, and take a look at the execution plan. I'd also see how much time it takes to execute the SQL query. (Add the SQL_NO_CACHE hint to bypass the MySQL cache, if that's enabled.) Maybe the query isn't making effective use of available indexes and/or suitable indexes aren't available. (And we're not seeing what the code is doing after the rows are returned from the database.)

Comment: @DanBracuk I simply display the product records info 20 at a time and paginate them.

Comment: @spencer7593 the Minimum and Maximum JVM Heap Size are two fields that you can set just above the JVM arguments in the CF Admin.  Also I don't see why retrieving mere 28K records would cause a problem to the CF server?

Comment: @spencer7593 the fields, category, userid, ranks are all indexed fields in tableA and userid is indexed on tableB also.   Does it matter what it does afterward since the error occur at the time of the cfquery?  I basically use the result set and display all the information 20 records at a time and paginate them for the user to see.  I just don't know what if there are 280K records then what will happen....

Comment: @Jack: Seems to me like you need to figure out if the error is related to the *number of rows returned*, or related to the *amount of time* the query runs, or if it's something else. Rather than speculate, I'd do what I suggested. That is, take the actual SQL text that is being sent to the MySQL server, take it to a different client, see how long it takes to execute. I'd also do some simple tests, like adding a LIMIT clause, to test whether "retrieving mere 1 records would cause a problem to the CF server?" Just my suggestions. (SO is a question/answer site, not a debugging service.)

Comment: @spencer7593 as I have mentioned, I have tried many way to resolve the issue.  it is _not_ always that the query will time out.  It will especially if there are search engines spider indexing the site.  It is sporadic that's why it's hard to hold it down.  In SO, it's place where we have issues that we can't figure out so the experts can help out.

Comment: If you are getting 28,000 records and only using 20 of them, perhaps you could look at ways of returning fewer records.  A filter on tableA.ranks might be appropriate.

Comment: @DanBracuk I am not just using 20 of them.  I show the user the first page (20 records) but the user can click on the page tabs to go to the next page.   So I need to get all 28K records so it can display the page tabs as well as last page tab in case the user may want to see the last page instead.  If you know a better way to do it, please do let me know.  That's also the reason I cache the query for 5 minutes in case the user browse around.  The category items may change every day, I was even thinking of cache for 24 hours....

Answer (score 3):

With 20-40k products per category at 20 categories with an unknown row size, you have some real architectural decisions to make on your data caching (if you do use a cache). Currently, each category id parameter will be a unique cache of that query with a time to live of five minutes consuming some amount of heap space. In addition, it has to be copied out of cache during a request and will consume memory until it can be collected. Also note that permgen is not related to heap size.

I would recommend not caching to see how the DB server handles it by only asking for the records for that page. Built in query cache is very situational and this is not one of those situations. 30k records might not seem like much until you realize you have product descriptions and other large text blocks that are half a meg each. I would highly recommend going with at least a gig or two of heap if you can for any typical commerce site with a robust catalog. (You say "I am running on CF9 on a server with 6GB RAM." Hopefully some of that is free to allocate to the JVM). In this situation, more memory is only going to put off the problem until a later date, if at all.

Also, pull permgen back to 256. 512 permgen is pretty high, even for a big enterprise app.

Here is how your app is currently functioning when a request comes in.

1. The query tag is hit and results are returned

   1. Cache hit - results are copied out of the cache taking some wasteful amount of megabytes
   2. Cache miss - results are streamed in from the database taking some wasteful amount of megabytes and are additionally copied into the cache region (but you avoid the database load time as well as transfer time, I suspect most of your time is spent during transfer rather than querying)
2. You utilize a fraction of the query
3. The query is garbage collected

Under light load, your server is probably barely keeping up. Who knows how often your cache region is able to avoid churn.

**Additional follow-up:**

It sounds like you are doing all this simply for the rowcounts for pagination. You can actually put your total row counts into the query that is returning records for just one page as a subquery. If you want to split into two queries -- one for the row counts and one for the records for this row, that former is a good contender for caching. It is data that won't change often, and if it does, it really doesn't matter if you are slightly behind. In addition, it is super small and actually makes sense to cache over asking the DB all the time.

Comment: I have 26 categories, some of them have 40K records.  So the MaxPermSize should be 256m?  What is considered enterprise app?  Currently I have about 200K requests a day.

Comment: Permgen is related to the number of Java classes and other Java entities. It's not "active" memory impacted by requests count. Heap is used for that. You would need a gigantic pile of classes to fill up 512 megs like millions of lines of code.

Comment: While I was researching, when there is a "Java heap space null" error why people are saying increase the "MaxPermSize"?

Comment: @jack I honestly don't know, but I would trust that I am sending you on the more correct path than trying to increase permgen.

Comment: *see how the DB server handles it by only asking for the records for that page*   Agreed. Look into [pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+pagination).

Comment: @J.T. I have now set the MaxPermSize down to 256 and increase the heap to 1024.  Will see how it goes.  Given the scenario I am facing #1 - people may or may not accessing all 26 different categories at different time during the day. #2 not all categories are updated daily but some categories are. #3 there are 20-40K records in each category and will increase in the future.  What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: @Leigh When people click on a category they would expect to see all the pages of that category and not just a page.  Is it possible to retrieve just 20 records and showing the pagination at the same time?  This would be a better solution?  Would that be hitting the DB every time the user click on a page tab?

Comment: Yes, you just include a column in the query that is just a count of the total records. SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE X=Y) total_count, other field, other field FROM tbl WHERE X=Y See the link Leigh posted for multiple pagination solutions for MySQL that don't involve swamping your application with unnecessary data.

Comment: If you were going to cache anything it would be a query that is just SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE id = <cfqueryparam>, but you can probably just do this in your one query as a subquery

Comment: @J.T. Just to be clear, so I would cache this -> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA
WHERE category <cfqueryparam value = "#cat#" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer" maxLength = "2">   then I would do the SELECT tableA.productid, tableA.userid....tableB.id, tableB.company....
FROM tableA LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.userid = tableB.userid WHERE tableA.category = <cfqueryparam value = "#cat#" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer" maxLength = "2">
ORDER by tableA.ranks DESC
LIMIT 0, 20 then I would do LIMIT 20, 20 and LIMIT 30, 20 and so on?

Comment: @J.T. wouldn't this accessing the DB for every page down grading the server, when there are thousands of requests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125451/discussion-between-j-t-and-jack).